# How old is Kitty Pryde in Earth 616?

Tags: marvel, x-men, age

When Kitty Pryde was introduced in *Uncanny X-Men* 129, she was described as being 13 years old. In *Uncanny X-Men* 141, we are shown a grown up Katherine Pryde - specifically in the year 2013. We are not explicitly told her age, but she is visibly older - arguably 30 years older than her then-current 13 year old self.

[image: First Appearance of Kitty Pryde]

Comics, in general, use a [sliding time scale](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Glossary:Sliding_Timescale) where time only really passes as necessary - or to make important relevant links to reality (e.g.: *The Amazing Spider-Man* #36). This, of course, [creates some continuity issues](https://web.archive.org/web/20150415043842/http://marvel.wikia.com/Marvel_Time) <sup>*(Archived link)*</sup> although we have now caught up with the year of *The Days Of Future Past*, none of the characters depicted have visibly aged nearly as much as the story showed us.

[image: Cover of Days of Future Past]

[image: Kate Pryde - closeup]

In Earth-616, Kitty has grown up and graduated college (though being a genius means this probably happened at an accelerated rate). She has graduated from the X-Men, joined Excalibur and returned back to the X-Men (repeatedly). From the very beginning there was a love interest between Kitty and Piotr Rasputin (Colossus), but editors [didn't approve of a 14 and 19 year old in a relationship](http://web.archive.org/web/20130215001421/https://uncannyxmen.net/db/issues/showquestion.asp?fldAuto=453) <sup>*(Archived link)*</sup>. They have since both grown up and consummated that relationship.

[image: Kitty and Colossus]

Despite there being a lot of attention being paid to her age early on, there does not seem to be many clues to Kitty's current age. **Are there any other indications of how old Kitty is in Earth-616?**

Comment: I think that her age was mentioned in one of the new "All new X-Men" books. If I recall correctly, she was still very young, but I have to check again.

Comment: There's also that period of time she spent phased while in that space bullet.  Does she age when she's phased?

Comment: She may not physically age, I'm not sure if that has ever been covered in the comics, but she would still be older. She was alive and aware all the time she was phased so she'd be older even if she hadn't physically aged.

Comment: With a sliding time scale, as characters get older, their ages compress together.  Thus Kitty was originally the "youngest" X-Man, much younger than founding members like Scott & Jean.  Now that she is older, there are many younger X-Men around, but Kitty is still younger than Scott, even though Scott is usually depicted as being in his early 40s at the oldest.

Comment: In the current comics, she's consistently treated as being around 30, give or take a few years.

Comment: I seem to recall she got a driver's license in Britain, during the early part of the EXCALIBUR run. She's gone to college; but, as she's supposed to be a genius, that tells us little about her actual age. When she got involved with Pete Wisdom, there may have been some objections, but because Wisdom is a jerk - no one brought up that she was jailbait. Of course, again, she was in Britain at the time.

Answer (score 2):

This can't really be answered definitively for a given reader date unless a particular comic pins down her age, but there was an article written about this very question, ["The Pryde Scale or Fun With Aging in the Marvel Universe"](https://observationdeck.kinja.com/the-pryde-scale-or-fun-with-aging-in-the-marvel-univers-1682155314) by Edward WinterRose (first published to The Bendis Board in 2008, then republished in 2015 at Observation Deck, which was [hosted by io9 at the time](https://web.archive.org/web/20150130030951/http://observationdeck.io9.com/the-pryde-scale-or-fun-with-aging-in-the-marvel-univers-1682155314)).

The formula for which it argues is 1 comic year for every 3.5 real-world years.

As noted there, it's a fair deduction that she was intended to be at least about 18 when she had a sexual relationship with significantly older Pete Wisdom in 1996. Moreover,

> The character of Kitty Pryde was introduced in 1980, and was described at the time as being 13 and a half. She was also described as being 14 in 1983 when The New Mutants got their own ongoing title. So far this is all stuff you already know. I WILL get to the point.
>
> My own take on it was that if Kitty Pryde was 21 years old at the time of her alleged termination (*Yeah, we'll see how long THAT lasts.*), then she's taken 28 reader years to age 8 character years. Breaking that down, (*and ignoring the fact that there's been a Christmas issue every year in Marvel Comics since 1980*), that would mean she's aged one character year for every 3.5 reader years. As well, everyone who was IN the X-Books since then should have aged at least 8 years since Kitty Pryde was introduced in 1980. I'm calling it 'The Pryde Scale' for easy future reference.
>
> ...
>
> Pryde Age / Reader Year
>   13 / 1980
>   14 / 1983 & 1/2
>   15 / 1987
>   16 / 1990 & 1/2 (Legal Adult, UK)
>   17 / 1994
>   18 / 1997 & 1/2 (Legal Adult, US)
>   19 / 2001
>   20 / 2004 & 1/2
>   21 / 2008 (Status: Unknown. Presumed Dead)

Or if you want it broken down by reader year, plugging the formula 13+(CurrentDate-1980)/3.5 into a spreadsheet gives us:

1980             13
1981             13.28571429
1982             13.57142857
1983             13.85714286
1984             14.14285714
1985             14.42857143
1986             14.71428571
1987             15
1988             15.28571429
1989             15.57142857
1990             15.85714286
1991             16.14285714
1992             16.42857143
1993             16.71428571
1994             17
1995             17.28571429
1996             17.57142857
1997             17.85714286
1998             18.14285714
1999             18.42857143
2000             18.71428571
2001             19
2002             19.28571429
2003             19.57142857
2004             19.85714286
2005             20.14285714
2006             20.42857143
2007             20.71428571
2008             21
2009             21.28571429
2010             21.57142857
2011             21.85714286
2012             22.14285714
2013             22.42857143
2014             22.71428571
2015             23
2016             23.28571429
2017             23.57142857
2018             23.85714286
2019             24.14285714
2020             24.42857143
2021             24.71428571
2022             25
2023             25.28571429
2024             25.57142857
2025             25.85714286
2026             26.14285714
2027             26.42857143
2028             26.71428571
2029             27
2030             27.28571429

However, while I don't know what her precise in-story birthday is, her Uncanny X-Men #129 first appearance was in January 1980, so if she was thirteen *and a half* at the time, perhaps the formula should be 13.5+(CurrentDate-1980)/3.5, in which case for the January of each reader year, the table should be:

1980             13.5
1981             13.78571429
1982             14.07142857
1983             14.35714286
1984             14.64285714
1985             14.92857143
1986             15.21428571
1987             15.5
1988             15.78571429
1989             16.07142857
1990             16.35714286
1991             16.64285714
1992             16.92857143
1993             17.21428571
1994             17.5
1995             17.78571429
1996             18.07142857
1997             18.35714286
1998             18.64285714
1999             18.92857143
2000             19.21428571
2001             19.5
2002             19.78571429
2003             20.07142857
2004             20.35714286
2005             20.64285714
2006             20.92857143
2007             21.21428571
2008             21.5
2009             21.78571429
2010             22.07142857
2011             22.35714286
2012             22.64285714
2013             22.92857143
2014             23.21428571
2015             23.5
2016             23.78571429
2017             24.07142857
2018             24.35714286
2019             24.64285714
2020             24.92857143
2021             25.21428571
2022             25.5
2023             25.78571429
2024             26.07142857
2025             26.35714286
2026             26.64285714
2027             26.92857143
2028             27.21428571
2029             27.5
2030             27.78571429

Answer (score 1):

Year 5 and Year 13 are 8 years apart so: 13.5+8= 21.5. I have no idea where 27 came from at all. As of now, 2020, we are in year 15 so she should be 23 but with the two timeskips, she should she 25.

Comment: This math is flawed

Answer (score 0):

The question seems simple enough, how old is she? That simply asks how many earth-years have passed since she was born.
As you stated, [she was 13-1/2 in 1980](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Katherine_Pryde_(Earth-616)) at her first appearance. That was 33 years before 2013.

Kitty Pryde is therefore 33+13-1/2 = **46-1/2** real-earth years old as of January 2013.

According to the Official Handbook of The Marvel Universe, she was 13-1/2 in Year 5 of the Modern Age of Heroes. 2013 is the end of Year 13. Therefore, in Marvel 616 Kitty Pryde is **27 years old**.

As I write this answer in 2019, Kitty Pride should be **29 years old**.

There are allegedly two time skips affecting her timeline: Claremont 2000 time skip, and the Secret Wars 2015 time skip. This would subtract 2 years from her age.

As to how old she appears, Marvel specifically warns that the sliding time scale  is a matter of interpretation, and there are parts of the scale that just don't work when applied to the most minuscule detail.

Likewise, because the time scale calendar has its origin at the Fantastic Four's space flight in FF#1, we do not know exactly when any birthdays or anniversaries are - The date of the space flight is not known.

Most importantly, when you see irregularities, they can be interpreted at the whim of the reader. That is the official stance of Marvel.

Comment: *That was 33 years before 2013.* This is true, but the question specifically asks about Earth-616 which has a sliding timescale. Simply subtracting the number between real-world dates doesn't work. In a 1997 issue of Spider-Man, Peter said he was 27, while he was 15 when he was introduced 35 real-world years earlier.